# empty website and git

Tags: asp.net, git, visual-studio-2012, github

hi as am a  newbie to GIT with visual studio ,
I'm working with an n-tier website with multiple projects and  at first i make it as an empty website , so the visual studio make a directory to the solution in Projects folders for VS2012 at documents and The BLL and DAL and the website pages itself at websites directory for visual studio main directory .
so when i trying to add the solution the source control this message shown up :

the current solution has projects that are located outside the solution folder.
there projects will not be source controlled in the git repository.
to add all the projects to a single Git repository please consolidate all projects under a single folder

i tried to copy the website into my solution folder but nothing happened of course :D 
how can i make this work  ?

thanks

Comment: Did you re-add the website with the new location to your solution in visual studio?

Comment: i didn't get what you mean !
but my visual studio always make the solution for my empty sites in the projects folder and the site itself in websites .

Comment: You copied your website to your solution folder, but have you changed the mapping to the website in visual studio?

Comment: no i tried to do that but i didn't get the way to do it , how can i do it ?

Comment: You can delete the website from the solution in visual studio, and then 'add existing project' to solution. Otherwise create a new empty website and enter the solution directory as the location for the website instead of the default location.

Comment: thanks a lot man , and when i want to make anew website the visual studio will always make to directories is there any way to avoid that ?

Comment: At the bottom of the new website dialog, the location is prefilled, but you can overwrite that just fine and enter the location you want.

Comment: I love you Stephen :D you can put your answer at the answer box due to mark it as useful :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete the website from the solution in visual studio, and then 'add existing project' to solution. Otherwise create a new empty website and enter the solution directory as the location for the website instead of the default location.

Comment: When entering the solution directory as the location for the website Visual Studio creates the folder and places the template files inside. Then it goes to create the solution project folder (with solution file enclosed) using the same name, but since the folder name already exists the solution project folder is appended with "(2)". @timsmith-aardwolf mentions this below and a process for fixing it, but is there a way to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2015 and the website templates for .NET Framework 4 (Looks like this has been sorted for templates targeting 4.5).

This is how I got the files from the template into the project

1. Click File -> New -> Web site
2. Select Templates -> Visual C# -> ASP.NET Web Forms Site
3. Leave Web location as File System and choose a folder. I used C:\Users\tim\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebSite4
4. Click OK

You'll now see in Windows Explorer there are two folders WebSite4 and WebSite4 (2). The second folder has the sln file and packages folder.

5. Create a folder in WebSite4 (2) called Website
6. Copy the contents of Website4 into WebSite4 (2)\Website

Return to Visual Studio

7. In Solution Explorer, right click WebSite4 and then click Remove. Click OK to confirm.
8. Right click Solution, click Add -> Existing Website.
9. Select the folder WebSite4 (2)\Website and click Open.

Bonus - rename the solution
10. Right click Solution 'WebSite4 (2)' and click Rename. Remove the (2)

Bonus - rename the folder

11. Rename the folder
12. Close the solution
13. Rename the folder in Windows Explorer
14. Open -> Project/Solution

Once that was all done I was able to publish the project to a remote git repository through Team Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to move the website files to the solution folder, it appears to be much easier to save a copy of the sln file to the websites folder from within Visual Studio. Then delete the original sln file in the projects folder. **Do not just move the sln files in file explorer**. The sln file contains paths, and by saving as a new sln the paths are updated.

The previous answer by @stephen seems like a great idea, but winds up creating duplicate folders in the Projects folder. Subsequently the sln file and the project files still wind up in different directories. @TimSmith-Aardwolf details correcting this, but it is a process.

The easiest way to proceed I've found is to go to **File > Save sln As...**  and select the website files folder.

[image: File Save menu]

This places a new identically named sln file inside the same folder as the website files. You do not have to close Visual Studio, Solution Explorer now lists the newly saved sln. Right click the Solution and select **Add to Source Control**.
I found this process [here](http://interestingwebs.blogspot.com/2014/05/add-asp-net-empty-web-site-to-git.html) and it works great.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution. I gave it a go this morning and it was easier than trying to move everything in Windows Explorer. But I did have problems with nuget relating to the Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB version="2.0.1" problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082137/unable-to-find-localdb-nuget-package To be fair, I've had this problem updating the nuget packages with my workaround but I couldn't get the site to build at all with this method. (TL:DR I wish I was using .NET 4.5!)

Comment: @TimSmith-Aardwolf I see. We'll thanks for trying it out. I am not using any database functionality, and I am targeting .NET 4.5, so I think I've gone as far as I can go on these issues for now.