# git not working with visual studio > file > new > web site ...

Tags: git, visual-studio

1- create a new empty website project in visual studio

[image: creating a new website project with visual studio]

2- adding project to source control

[image: adding project to source control]

3- error

[image]

Comment: What don't you understand about the message?

Comment: how to add [visual studio > file > new > web site …] projects to git source control ?

Comment: Consolidate the projects into subdirectories of the solution folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the bottom of the `New Web Site` dialog: the location is pre-filled, but you can overwrite that and enter the location you want.

So you can delete your solution and start over, this time with a web site folder path within your project.

You find a similar advice in "[empty website and git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18052076/6309)", which is more than what you see in "[Visual Studio Tools for Git should support projects located outside the solution directory](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4135554-visual-studio-tools-for-git-should-support-project)" (a suggestion which is for now ignored)