# Unable to find localdb nuget package

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, azure-devops

when i build (F5 debug) a new default project (web application) on my local VS2103 machine everything runs fine.

when i try to build the same project in Visual Studio Online, i receive build errors:

> Unable to find version '2.0.1' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB'.
>
> Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe

the package.config file includes this line:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
```

when i change the localdb version to 2.0.0 in the packages.config file, the build runs fine on vso. this version is listed on nuget.org.

i also see that on the local vs2013 machine, version 2.0.1 of the localdb package is present. however, nuget.org does not list this version.

how do i get NuGet to include the newer 2.0.1 version? Or, how do i get the 2.0.1 version from my local vs2013 machine to be included in the vso build?

Comment: i checked the vs2013 solution's "Manage NuGet packages for Solution" and it shows that version 2.0.1 is installed locally.  i do not see any banner messages.

Comment: NuGet caches packages locally in user AppData so it's possible it is coming from there. That could only happen if at some point v2.0.1 was available on the official NuGet feed, or if you are using your own NuGet feed. A quick google search should tell you how to delete NuGet cache

Comment: i do not have my own feed.  this project is a default vs2013 web app project from microsoft.  (VS2013>File>New Project>Templates>VB>Web>ASP.NET Web Forms Application) no changes were made by me. i would like to continue to use the latest version 2.0.1.

Comment: I took a look at the template and strangely it does install version 2.0.1. I've updated my answer with my thoughts - hope it helps

Comment: nice to know that someone else sees the same problem.  i would like to use the latest version. is there a way to get version 2.0.1 on NuGet? or have VSO access the local package in some way?  (btw, clearing the local NuGet cache did not make a difference.)

Answer (score 7):

As you rightly point out, Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB version 2.0.1 does not exist in NuGet. If you create a new application in VS2013 and add that reference to the packages.config, the solution will still build, but it will fail to download that package. You can see this by right clicking on the solution and selecting "Manage NuGet Packages...". There will be a banner at the top saying that some dependencies failed to download.

If you are sure that you need this package in your solution, then the fix is to change the reference to 2.0.0.

**Update**

I had took a closer look at this. Previously I had tested this with a console app, but it seems you are right - when creating a .NET 4.0 Web Forms project, a reference is added to NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB version 2.0.1. If you then delete the packages folder (next to your solution file) and build, you will see the error I mention above since NuGet is unable to restore the package. I'm guessing there is a problem with the project template itself, or Microsoft removed version 2.0.1 from public NuGet for some reason. Either way, the solution is still the same; depend on the version that is available in NuGet.

Comment: In my case there were duplicate entries in the package.config file, so I backed up and remove the one referring to 2.1.  Rebuild and resolved.  Thanks for putting me on the right path.