# Create Visual Studio Web Site project entirely in git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I need to build a website in Visual Studio 2015 that other people can contribute to. Git is the versioning platform of choice.

If I create a website in Visual Studio with File -> New -> Web Site with the Web Location set to File System -> C:\GitProjects\Website1, the sln file is stored in a completely different folder (C:\Users\tim\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Website1)

That means the sln file isn't in the git repository and other people can't open it or the project.

How should I set up the project in VS2015 so we can all work on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit convoluted but the answer is to create a folder for the website (I called it Website) in the folder containing the sln file. This is probably the folder with (2) at the end because VS tries to create two folders with the same name.

I created the website with File, New, Web Site. Then Templates, Visual C#, ASP.NET Web Forms Site.

Copy the contents of the folder created for the website by VS into the Website folder in the folder with the sln file.

Return to Visual Studio. Right click the Website in Solution Explorer and click Remove. The solution file should be the only entry in Solution Explorer.

Right click the solution, click Add and then Existing website. Find the Website folder and then click Open. Everything should now be in a single folder that you can add to a git repository.

Before you do that, it's a good idea to rename the solution (from within VS) and the folder to remove the (2)

I wrote a full step by step at [empty website and git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052076/empty-website-and-git/45959130#45959130)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to move the website files to the solution folder, it appears to be much easier to save a copy of the sln file to the websites folder from within Visual Studio. Then delete the original sln file in the projects folder. **Do not just move the sln files in file explorer**. The sln file contains paths, and by saving as a new sln the paths are updated.

Thanks to @TimSmith-Aardwolf for his answer and linking to his more detailed answer. I've place my more detailed answer in that [same post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46101617/1208190).

Answer (score 0):

Store the project in any directory you want, then go to that directory and do `git init` to create a new git repository.

Simple guide to getting started with git: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Full docs: https://git-scm.com/doc

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't answer the question that Visual Studio puts the sln file (and packages folder) in a different folder to the website. I've tried moving the sln file and that didn't work