# Projects are located outside the Solution Error

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio-2015

After checkout the code from GIT, while opening a solution, am getting this below error, and if i build some of this Project using msbuild.exe through command mode it is throwing same error. But visual studio builds all the project successfully.

[image]

do you guys know what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [in this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/48f7cd1f-9f61-4c14-af4a-715ae54d19dc/the-current-solution-has-projects-that-are-located-outside-the-solution-folder-so-i-cant-add?forum=visualstudiogeneral):

> You could check the `.sln` file to see the paths inside there. There should be lines inside which start with Project and have this format:

```
Project("{guid}") = "Name of Project", "Path\Projectfile", "{guid}"
```

> Please check the paths - they should all be relative and should not leave the solution directory.

For a project involving website template, you can [follow those steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45959130/6309).